# Issue with inserting a custom cover page

Tags: lyx, covers

I am a beginner of `latex` and I use `lyx` as my tool. I finished my document with `Lyx` and found a cover page template from [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/title-pages)(the first template in the page)

I copied the code into my lyx file in the beginning of the page. As instructions says I copied the title page code and then the `\titleGP` code snippet. But it says it is wrong in compile time. Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Which error do you get exactly? It works fine here, with the default settings in LyX.

Comment: Where should I put that code. In preamble mode??

Comment: ` \inputencoding{latin1} \documentclass
                                          {book}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you copy-paste to the correct place, this should work fine.

First, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and paste in everything from the preamble of that template. That means everything between, *but not including*, `\documentclass{book}` and `\begin{document}`. (Lines 29 to 64 in the template)

Second, exit the document settings, add an ERT (Insert --> TeX code, or Ctrl + L) at the start of your document, and type `\thispagestyle{empty}\titleGP` in this.

Comment: it says you haven't loaded the option english yet

Comment: @user3892439 That error has nothing to do with the cover page. Try closing and reopening LyX, then re-generate the PDF.